# SASS/SCSS Sticky nothing happens

Tags: html, sass

I can't get my `positon: sticky` to work, nothing happens when I'm adding it to the "`th`" in the scss.

The HTML & SCSS looks like this(urls modified):

https://jsfiddle.net/rtsyjmeL/1/

Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong / missing?

Comment: It seems to not work in the jsfiddle, as the import file is not there. But I copied the styles to a codepen and there it worked. So in my opinion it should work.

Comment: @Gh05d so it might be something in my imported file that overrides it or something then?

Comment: It could be if there is something in there which is more specific, or carries the `!important` hammer for position somewhere. Do you target the `th` there?